# How to setup SMTP Postfix server to recieve messages from PHPMailer

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, phpmailer, postfix-mta

I'm setting up a new SMTP server (server A) that is supposed to recieve information from a simple LAMP installation using PHPMailer on server B.

I've just been following the [postfix installation guide from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04) for server A and then running [this PHPMailer script](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps) on server B. When I execute the script I always get the following:

`2019-04-14 06:00:35 Connection: opening to XXX.XX.XX.XXX:25, timeout=30, options=array() 2019-04-14 06:00:36   Connection failed.`

`Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to XXX.XX.XX.XXX:25 (Connection refused) [/public_html/plugins/php-mailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]`

`2019-04-14 06:00:36 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) SMTP error: Connect failed`

Here's what I have done:

- I've verifed that my installation of PHPMailer works by test-sending an email from localhost
- I've verified that my postfix installation works correctly by creating an email in the local terminal which sent successfully to the destination address
- I have tried various ports and options with phpmailer (SSL with port 465, TLS with port 25 and 587). I also allowed them in my DigitalOcean firewall and verified they were open with the `netstat -tulpn` command
- I've tried setting the hostname of the postfix server to various domains that I own and I've trying changing various other settings to see if it was a problem with the server restricing access to only localhost.

I've had no luck so far. A point in any direction would be great. Thanks

Comment: This does sound like a firewall problem. What happens if you telnet to port 25 on your mail from your sending server?

Comment: Hi Synchro, I agree, I thought it was a firewall issue too but my port 25 on Server B is open...

Comment: Sure but it may not be *your* firewall that's stopping it. If you can't telnet to it from your other server, and you get connection refused or a timeout, it's being firewalled *by something*, most likely your hosting provider. Don't assume – **check**!

Comment: Yeah that's it, Telnetting locally brings back a result but tellnetting externally gives me connection refused. I'll do some research speaking with my hosting providers and playing with both firewalls and come back if I find anything! Thanks